# Scope that does not show current users resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

In my `Product` model I'm trying to make a scope that doesn't show the current users products.

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.not_current_users_products
    where(:user_id => current_user == nil)
  end
end
```

This should look at the current user and see if the products belong to him or not.

How would I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While there are some hacks out there to make `current_user` available to your models, it isn't by default. You could set up the method to be a little more generic, then pass in your current_user:

```
def self.except_for_user(user)
  where("user_id != ?", user.id)
end
```

Then call it with:

```
Product.except_for_user(current_user)
```